# Format Y-Axis of a chart to 1M, 2M, 3M, etc

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I would like to format the Y-Axis of a chart.

At the moment, the values on Y-Axis are 1000000, 2000000, 3000000, 4000000, 5000000.

What I would like to display is 1M, 2M, 3M, 4M, 5M.

I found the place to custom the format, however, I don't know what format code to use.

Note that I cannot use formulas in cells to change these values, because in the chart, I still want to see exact values in data points
such as `479,521`, `1,234,500`, etc.

Could anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the Y-axis, select Format Axis.

[image]

Go to the Number section, set Category to `Custom` and enter the following on the Format Code box: `[>999999]  #,,"M";#0`. Click <kbd>Add</kbd>. In case you want to show 1 decimal place for thousands, you can enter the following `[>999999]  #.#,,"M";#0`.

[image]

The Y axis will show a `M` beside the number when it is 1 million or more.

[image]